# Immediate constituent analysis

Tags: syntax-trees

Practicing immediate constituent analysis using a "toy" context-free phrase structure grammar of English is a great way to introduce undergraduate students to syntactic analysis. In the context of a course in English syntax, the following sentence came up as controversial, with different plausible parses considered. Do community members have a consensus parse for this sentence?

> Mysterious wizards concoct potions cleverly in the early morning if the sun rises.

Comment: The only ambiguity I can see is the scope of "cleverly". I.e. does it scope over the prepositional phrase or not?

Comment: The scope of the conditional is also ambiguous.

Comment: Either way, this sentence does not look very natural to me, at least not in prose...

Comment: Is the nonsensical "if" instead of "when" there on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence could have a few different possible parses, though not all of them will be obvious. If you plug the sentence into the [LinGO English Resource Grammar (ERG)](http://erg.delph-in.net/logon), which is an HPSG-based automatic parser, you can see the possible parses. The first one is probably the most obvious one.

Comment: Would it be possible t provide these options in the answer? There are only four, but it might be a little difficult.